# Vimeo (video file link) is not playing in Safari

Tags: video, safari, html5-video, vimeo, video-codecs

We are hosting a bunch of videos on Vimeo and using their 'Video file link' on our site to access the videos directly (instead of embeds).

**While they play perfectly on Chrome, they don't seem to play on Safari. [Example of a link provided directly from Vimeo (video file link).](https://player.vimeo.com/external/659513518.sd.mp4?s=2f3c50c461c7c5cb562b8d60fe8961957f6cde2e&profile_id=165)**

Things to note:

- The files are in mp4 and compressed through Media Encoder before uploaded to Vimeo.
- A few times it randomly started playing on Safari but stop working again after refreshing.
- We have tried to 'Allow All Auto-Play' in Safari settings to make sure that's not the issue.
- The Vimeo settings are set to 'Private on your account, but embeddable anywhere.' Allow downloads is enabled as well.

The actual site that the videos are being used on is called [STEEP](https://steep2.webflow.io/).
While the code isn't the problem (as the Vimeo video can't even be played when the URL is inputted directly in Safari), i've added it anyway for later context:

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" loop poster="">
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/659513518.sd.mp4?s=2f3c50c461c7c5cb562b8d60fe8961957f6cde2e&profile_id=165" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```